# How to return insert id from room db

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am using room db with mvvm.
i want to retrieve id when user add new item in room db.
i am using Executors insted of aysncTask (deprecated).
this is want i am using now.

`Student.java`

```
package ask2784.studentsdetails;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Ignore;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "students_table")
public class Student {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "father_name")
    private String fatherName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "class_name")
    private String className;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "attendens", defaultValue = "0")
    private int attendens;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_presents", defaultValue = "0")
    private int totalPresents;

    @Ignore
    public Student() {}

    public Student(String name, String fatherName, String className) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
        this.className = className;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFatherName() {
        return this.fatherName;
    }

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return this.className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public int getAttendens() {
        return this.attendens;
    }

    public void setAttendens(int attendens) {
        this.attendens = attendens;
    }

    public int getTotalPresents() {
        return this.totalPresents;
    }

    public void setTotalPresents(int totalPresents) {
        this.totalPresents = totalPresents;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return getName().equals(student.getName())
                && getFatherName().equals(student.getFatherName())
                && getClassName().equals(student.getClassName())
                && getAttendens() == student.getAttendens()
                && getTotalPresents() == student.getTotalPresents();
    }

    public static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Student> DIFF_CALLBACK =
            new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Student>() {
                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(Student oldStudent, Student newStudent) {
                    return oldStudent.getId() == newStudent.getId();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(Student oldStudent, Student newStudent) {
                    return oldStudent.equals(newStudent);
                }
            };
}
```

`StudentDao.java`

```
package ask2784.studentsdetails;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface StudentDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Student student);

    @Update
    void update(Student student);

    @Delete
    void delete(Student student);

    @Query("DELETE FROM students_table")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM students_table ORDER BY name, father_name COLLATE NOCASE")
    LiveData<List<Student>> getAll();
}
```

`StudentsRepo.java`

```
package ask2784.studentsdetails;

import android.app.Application;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class StudentsRepo {
    private StudentDao studentDao;
    private LiveData<List<Student>> allStudents;
    private Executor service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public StudentsRepo(Application application) {
        StudentsDatabase db = StudentsDatabase.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
        studentDao = db.studentDao();
        allStudents = studentDao.getAll();
    }

    public void insert(Student student) {
        service.execute(
                () -> {
                    studentDao.insert(student);
                });
    }

    public void update(Student student) {
        service.execute(
                () -> {
                    studentDao.update(student);
                });
    }

    public void delete(Student student) {
        service.execute(
                () -> {
                    studentDao.delete(student);
                });
    }

    public void deleteAllStudents() {
        service.execute(
                () -> {
                    studentDao.deleteAll();
                });
    }

    public LiveData<List<Student>> getAllStudents() {
        return allStudents;
    }
}
```

`StudentViewModel.java`

```
import android.app.Application;

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;

public class StudentViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private StudentsRepo repo;
    private LiveData<List<Student>> allStudents;

    public StudentViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        repo = new StudentsRepo(application);
        allStudents = repo.getAllStudents();
    }

    public void insert(Student student) {
        repo.insert(student);
    }

    public void update(Student student) {
        repo.update(student);
    }

    public void delete(Student student) {
        repo.delete(student);
    }

    public void deleteAllStudents() {
        repo.deleteAllStudents();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Student>> getAllStudents() {
        return allStudents;
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve insertedId when new Student added to room database.
but i dont want to use `LiveData<Object>`

```
 @Insert
 long insert(Student student);
```

and use in
`StudentsRepo.java`
like

```
public long insert(Student student){
   return studentDao.insert(student); // return inserted id
}
```

also want getStudentById method;
but i dont know how to return value from `Executors.execute(()->{});`

Answer (score 1):

When you use @Insert annotation, It will return a `long` value which is row Id.

You declared it:

```
@Insert
long insert(Student student);
```

So:

```
Long rowId = someDao.insert(student);
```

And for getting a row with Id you can use `@Query`:

```
@Query("select * from student where id = :id")
Student getStudentById(int id);
```

As for suggestions, Don't use Executors in the Repository. Use them in the ViewModel to handle the result correctly. And if you want to be more advanced, Learn RxJava. Or Use Kotlin.

Good luck.

Comment: Getting error while insert Item using that method, ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=260958584, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=ask2784.studentsdetails/.StudentActivity (has extras) }} to activity {ask2784.studentsdetails/ask2784.studentsdetails.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.```

Comment: when is use `allowMainThreadQueries` in database. I am not able to getStudentById(id) after insert.

Comment: Don't do IO work on the MainThread, Read this article from Google to learn how to use Futures and Executors to communicate between ViewModel and Repository to get the data. https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous/java-threads